# Android, NDK, prebuilt '.o' file is deleted by the build system

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

1. I am trying to link my exe w/ a pre-built '.o' object file ( consisting of a binary resource ).
2. the object file is located under '$(LOCAL_PATH)/dependency'.
3. Using a FileSys monitor, I can see that during compilation the Build system deletes the pre-built '.o' file.
4. using 'LOCAL_OBJECTS += 'dependency/prebuilt.o' doesn't help.

**How can I prevent Android build system from deleting my pre-built '.o' file ?**

### A snap of the makefile used

```
LOCAL_PATH       := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE     := MyTestApp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := main.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := 
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_CFLAGS     := 
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS   := 
LOCAL_LDFLAGS    := -Wl,--format=binary -Wl,Resources/MyBinRsrc -Wl,--output=dependency/MyBinRsrc.o -Wl,--format=elf,dependency/MyBinRsrc.o -Wl,--format=default
COMMON_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)
LOCAL_OBJECTS    += dependency/MyBinRsrc.o
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: Please describe the full makefile that generates it. If the .o file is generated during the ndk-build process, it is by no means "prebuilt". A stray .o file generated by ndk-build, and a prebuilt .o file are two completely different things.

Comment: makefile snap added to the original post

Comment: So, in this case, the file is not prebuilt at all, it is generated during the same build stage where you want to use it. ndk-build does not know what stage actually will generate the file. You can try generating the .o file with one separate Android.mk file in a separate project, then wrap it into a static library as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928744, and use that as a normal prebuilt static library.

Comment: I get the same problem when trying to wrap w/ a static lib, the '.o' file is deleted before the '.a' file is generated...

Comment: Is the file deleted even if you don't list it in `LOCAL_OBJECTS`? Then you can probably generate it manually by calling ld (the right one from the right android toolchain) to generate the .o file.